chartjs 4 - ecg graph with 12 derivations, problems with the scale
I'm building a graph in chartjs to show ECG data. The data comes from PHP/Livewire, but, let's say that the data is an array.
For context a typical ECG comes in a grid representing 25mm/s (x = time) and 10mm/mV (y = amplitude). Basically each line/step in x equals to 40ms and in y equals to 0.1mV. Let's say the max amplitude is 2000 and the min is -300, we need a grid with 23 little lines to accommodate this line/derivation, remember that
My chart works great, but the canvas has a configured width and height.
<canvas id="ecgChart" style="width: 6000px; height: 500px;"></canvas>

Since the graph has 12 derivations/datasets, if one of them has an huge amplitude, the squares changes the scale. Increasing to canvas to 1000px should resolve almost every case but no one wants a 1000px height graph in the dashboard, specially if the grid has rules.
After the rendering I take a screenshot of every dataset to build a report. It's working but the scales are messed up because of the problem that I described.
My js code is:
<script>

    // Renders the main chart
    console.log('ECG Main Chart: Rendering...');
    const ecgChart_ctx = document.getElementById('ecgChart').getContext('2d');
    const ecgChart = new Chart(ecgChart_ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: Array.from({ length: $wire.maximum_ecg_signals }, (_, i) => i),
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: $wire.datasets['I']['label'],
                    data: $wire.datasets['I']['values'],
                    borderColor: `hsl(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999) + 1}, 60%, 50%)`,
                    borderWidth: 2.5,
                    fill: false,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    hidden: true,
                },
                {
                    label: $wire.datasets['II']['label'],
                    data: $wire.datasets['II']['values'],
                    borderColor: `hsl(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999) + 1}, 60%, 50%)`,
                    borderWidth: 2.5,
                    fill: false,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    hidden: true,
                },
                {
                    label: $wire.datasets['III']['label'],
                    data: $wire.datasets['III']['values'],
                    borderColor: `hsl(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999) + 1}, 60%, 50%)`,
                    borderWidth: 2.5,
                    fill: false,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    hidden: true,
                },
                {
                    label: $wire.datasets['aVR']['label'],
                    data: $wire.datasets['aVR']['values'],
                    borderColor: `hsl(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999) + 1}, 60%, 50%)`,
                    borderWidth: 2.5,
                    fill: false,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    hidden: true,
                },
                {
                    label: $wire.datasets['aVL']['label'],
                    data: $wire.datasets['aVL']['values'],
                    borderColor: `hsl(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999) + 1}, 60%, 50%)`,
                    borderWidth: 2.5,
                    fill: false,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    hidden: true,
                },
                {
                    label: $wire.datasets['aVF']['label'],
                    data: $wire.datasets['aVF']['values'],
                    borderColor: `hsl(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999) + 1}, 60%, 50%)`,
                    borderWidth: 2.5,
                    fill: false,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    hidden: true,
                },
                {
                    label: $wire.datasets['V1']['label'],
                    data: $wire.datasets['V1']['values'],
                    borderColor: `hsl(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999) + 1}, 60%, 50%)`,
                    borderWidth: 2.5,
                    fill: false,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    hidden: true,
                },
                {
                    label: $wire.datasets['V2']['label'],
                    data: $wire.datasets['V2']['values'],
                    borderColor: `hsl(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999) + 1}, 60%, 50%)`,
                    borderWidth: 2.5,
                    fill: false,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    hidden: true,
                },
                {
                    label: $wire.datasets['V3']['label'],
                    data: $wire.datasets['V3']['values'],
                    borderColor: `hsl(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999) + 1}, 60%, 50%)`,
                    borderWidth: 2.5,
                    fill: false,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    hidden: true,
                },
                {
                    label: $wire.datasets['V4']['label'],
                    data: $wire.datasets['V4']['values'],
                    borderColor: `hsl(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999) + 1}, 60%, 50%)`,
                    borderWidth: 2.5,
                    fill: false,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    hidden: true,
                },
                {
                    label: $wire.datasets['V5']['label'],
                    data: $wire.datasets['V5']['values'],
                    borderColor: `hsl(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999) + 1}, 60%, 50%)`,
                    borderWidth: 2.5,
                    fill: false,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    hidden: true,
                },
                {
                    label: $wire.datasets['V6']['label'],
                    data: $wire.datasets['V6']['values'],
                    borderColor: `hsl(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999) + 1}, 60%, 50%)`,
                    borderWidth: 2.5,
                    fill: false,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    hidden: true,
                },

            ],
        },
        options: {
            animation: false, // Must have!
            normalized: true,
            responsive: false,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            interaction: {
                enabled: true, // Ensure that the tooltip is activated
                mode: 'nearest', // Tooltip exhibition mode: index or nearest
                intersect: false, // Tooltip only shows when the mouse is above a point
                axis: 'xy',
            },
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'bottom',
                    title: {
                        display: false,
                        text: 'Tempo (ms)'
                    },
                    //min: 0, // This is the starting point on x-axis
                    //max: $wire.maximum_ecg_signals, // This is the ending point on x-axis, typically will be 10000 points (10seconds)
                    ticks: {
                        callback: function(value) {

                            // Doesn't show times (ms) labels on x-axis
                            return '';

                            // Show times (ms) labels on x-axis
                            /*if (value % 200 === 0) {
                                return '200 ms';
                            } else if (value % 40 === 0) {
                                return '40 ms';
                            } else {
                                return '';
                            }*/

                        },
                        // Defines the ticks interval on x-axis,
                        // On a typical ecg grid, 1 little square represents 40ms,
                        // On a typical ecg grid, 1 big square represents 200ms (5 little squares)
                        stepSize: 40,
                    },
                    grid: {
                        drawOnChartArea: true,
                        lineWidth: (context) => {
                            // Grid line thickness on x-axis,
                            // Show a thick line every 200 ticks and a thin line every 40
                            if (context.tick.value % 200 === 0) return 2;
                            if (context.tick.value % 40 === 0) return 1;
                            return 0;
                        },
                        color: (context) => {
                            // For every 200 ms (5 little squares), the line color should be darker,
                            // For every 40 ms (1 little square), the line color should be lighter
                            if (context.tick.value % 200 === 0) return 'rgb(250, 117, 117)';
                            if (context.tick.value % 40 === 0) return 'rgb(250, 155, 155)';
                            return 'transparent';
                        }
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    title: {
                        display: false,
                        text: 'Amplitude (mV)'
                    },
                    //min: $wire.datasets_min_y, // This is the minimum amplitude, should be the min() value of a derivation
                    //max: $wire.datasets_max_y, // This is the maximum amplitude, should be the max() value of a derivation
                    ticks: {
                        callback: function(value) {

                            // Doesn't show mV labels on x-axis
                            return '';

                            // Show mV labels on x-axis
                            //if (value % 500 === 0) return '0.5mV';
                            //if (value % 100 === 0) return '0.1mV';
                            //return '';

                        },
                        // Defines the ticks interval on y-axis
                        // On a typical ecg grid, 1 little square represents 0.1mV,
                        // On a typical ecg grid, 1 big square represents 0.5mV,
                        // On a typical ecg grid, 2 big square represents 1mV
                        stepSize: 100
                    },
                    grid: {
                        drawOnChartArea: true,
                        lineWidth: (context) => {
                            // Grid line thickness on y-axis,
                            // Show a thick line every 0.5mV (500 ticks) and a thin line every 0.1mV (100 ticks)
                            if (context.tick.value % 500 === 0) return 2; // Linha grossa
                            if (context.tick.value % 100 === 0) return 1; // Linha fina
                            return 0; // Linhas não visíveis
                        },
                        color: (context) => {
                            // For every 0.5mV (500 ticks, 1 big square), the line color should be darker,
                            // For every 0.1mV (100 ticks, 1 little square), the line color should be lighter
                            if (context.tick.value % 500 === 0) return 'rgb(250, 117, 117)';
                            if (context.tick.value % 100 === 0) return 'rgb(250, 155, 155)';
                            return 'transparent';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            plugins: {
                tooltip: {
                    enable: false,
                },
                corsair: {
                    color: 'black',
                },
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    position: 'top',
                    align: 'start',
                    fillStyle: '#000000',
                },
                zoom: {
                    pan: {
                        enabled: true,
                        mode: 'x',
                    },
                    zoom: {
                        wheel: {
                            enabled: false,
                        },
                        pinch: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        mode: 'xy',
                    }
                },
            }
        },
        plugins: [
            {
                id: 'corsair',
                defaults: {
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#FF4949',
                    dash: [3, 3],
                },
                afterInit: (chart, args, opts) => {
                    chart.corsair = {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                    }
                },
                afterEvent: (chart, args) => {
                    const {inChartArea} = args
                    const {type,x,y} = args.event

                    chart.corsair = {x, y, draw: inChartArea}
                    chart.draw()
                },
                beforeDatasetsDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
                    const {ctx} = chart
                    const {top, bottom, left, right} = chart.chartArea
                    const {x, y, draw} = chart.corsair
                    if (!draw) return

                    ctx.save()

                    ctx.beginPath()
                    ctx.lineWidth = opts.width
                    ctx.strokeStyle = opts.color
                    ctx.setLineDash(opts.dash)
                    ctx.moveTo(x, bottom)
                    ctx.lineTo(x, top)
                    ctx.moveTo(left, y)
                    ctx.lineTo(right, y)
                    ctx.stroke()

                    ctx.restore()
                }
            }
        ]
    });
    console.log('ECG Main Chart: Rendered!');

</script>

Example 1 (OK) - using the code above:

Scale OK, top circle has 101 and the lower -910. Need 10 lines in y 10mV (0.1mV /line)
Example 2 (NOT OK) - using the code above:

Scale NOT OK, top circle has 2239 and the lower -811. Need almost 31 lines in y 30mV (0.1mV /line)
Does anyone have a clue to help me out?
I'm open to try different libraries.
PS: I tried d3js but didn't manage to get it work.
Regards/Thanks,
Helder

By your description, the scale of the chart will adapt in order to accommodate the curve with the highest amplitude. It's unclear what else do you want to happen.

The scale isn't right, the squares can't change because of the resolution. The scale needs to grow if the amplitude requires.

That behavior must have been implemented in your code; the default behavior of chart.js is to rescale the chart when a dataset is disabled or enabled through the legend, see fiddle.

Still not very clear what you want to achieve, but if by any chance the issue is that the value of scales.y.ticks.stepSize is not always honoured, you have to also set scales.y.ticks.autoSkip: false.

@kikon, you actually solved the problem with autoSkip:false :) now, the grid is an ECG grid! Create an answer please.

I have the code to take SS and send It to backend. Thanks anyway
